# Hi, i need a result of all attributes including the properties when we right click the documents and see

Tags: d, documentum

I want all the mandatory single and repeating attributes and also the properties when we see by right click the documents for the Archive cabinet. I tried the below query in Oracle SQL Developer :

```
select r_object_id, object_name, r_object_type, title, subject,
    r_creation_date, r_modify_date, r_modifier, a_content_type, 
    i_contents_id, i_cabinet_id,owner_name,i_chronicle_id,authors,keywords,
    i_folder_id,r_version_label
FROM IPEDMS.dm_sysobject_s, IPEDMS.dm_sysobject_r 
WHERE IPEDMS.dm_sysobject_s.r_object_id = IPEDMS.dm_sysobject_r.r_object_id 
 and r_object_id in (select * from ip_indexcard_doc_s);
```

Please let me know the correct query.

Note: in the ip_indexcard_doc_s table only i found those properties when we right click the documeents under archive.

Comment: And what is wrong with your SELECT query? Some documents are missing or what? And why are you using SQL and not DQL?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look in the dm_type_xxx tables along with some other tables.

Easiest way to find out is to install the dqMan from FME and work your way though that. It's free and very good for working with docbases.

And as stated by @cgrim above, you should consider to use DQL instead unless you really understand the Documentum object model.